# Does Braintree support payment in installments?

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree, payment-processing

I can't find anything related to installment plans in the docs, except recurring payment (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview), which to me seems to be related to subscriptions only

Comment: Is there a difference between recurring payments (where you specify the length of the recurring payments) and instalments ?

Comment: it is my understanding that recurring billing, as described in the docs https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview can be cancelled anytime since it is subscription based, while payment in installments is predetermined and used to make payment easier for the customer since he doesn't have to pay the full amount immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installment payments are not specifically offered as a Braintree payment method, but they do provide guidance for PayPal Pay Later:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/pay-later-offers/javascript/v3